# Flutter Windows: "error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member"

Tags: flutter, flutter-windows

I have added Windows platform support to my existing Flutter project with `flutter create --platforms=windows .` but when I try to run it, it gives me the following error:

```
C:\Users\sabbi\dev\flutter_app\windows\flutter\ephemeral\.plugin_symlinks\connectivity_plus_windows\windows\connectivity_plus_windows_plugin.cpp(94,3): error C2597: illegal reference to non-static member '`anonymous-namespace'::ConnectivityPlusWindowsPlugin::_eventChannel' [C:\Users\sabbi\dev\flutter_app\build\windows\plugins\connectivity_plus_windows\connectivity_plus_windows_plugin.vcxproj]
```

I've already tried `flutter clean` but it did nothing.

Comment: That's a C++ error. If the generated code is faulty, you should write a bug report. However, for a start, extract and provide a [mcve]. Without, it's impossible to say whether your code/actions are at fault or flutter's.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt It was the connectivity package that was causing the error. I replaced it with connectivity_plus package and it worked